# Javascript Tree Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, jstree

I have installed the grails plugin for [jstree](https://www.jstree.com/). I cant seem to get it working right.

It doesnt seem to be a resource problem as you will find below. I have no idea what it wont work.

This is my html

```
<div id="jstree">
    <ul>
        <li>Folder 1
            <ul>
                <li id="child_1">Child 1</li>
                <li>Child 2</li>
                <li id="child_2">Child 1</li>
                <li>Child 2</li>
                <li id="child_3">Child 1</li>
                <li>Child 2</li>
                <li id="child_4">Child 1</li>
                <li>Child 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Folder 2</li>
        <ul>
            <li id="child_5">Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
            <li id="child_6">Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
            <li id="child_7">Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
            <li id="child_8">Child 1</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then my javascript is

```
$(function () {
    $('#jstree').jstree();
});
```

[image]

I got this ^^
It allowed me to click on it to expand the first folders child nodes but not the second.
Then I tried this javascript

```
$(function () {
    $("#jstree").jstree({ "plugins" : [ "themes", "default" ] });
});
```

[image]

I got this^^
Clicking on it does nothing

Then I tied this

```
$(function () {
    $('#jstree').jstree();
});


$("#jstree").jstree({
    "themes": {
        "theme": "default",
        "dots": true,
        "icons": true,
        "url": "/css/jstree/themes/default/style.css"
    },
    "plugins" : [ "themes", "ui" ]
});
```

[image]

I got this^^

Could this be a compatibility issue, the reason I dont think it is is because it works for me on other site as in jstree.com

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your html structure is incorrect, you have include the second `<ul>` inside `<li>`

```js
$('#jstree').jstree();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />

<div id="jstree">
    <ul>
        <li>Folder 1
            <ul>
                <li id="child_1">Child 1</li>
                <li>Child 2</li>
                <li id="child_2">Child 1</li>
                <li>Child 2</li>
                <li id="child_3">Child 1</li>
                <li>Child 2</li>
                <li id="child_4">Child 1</li>
                <li>Child 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Folder 2
          <ul>
              <li id="child_5">Child 1</li>
              <li>Child 2</li>
              <li id="child_6">Child 1</li>
              <li>Child 2</li>
              <li id="child_7">Child 1</li>
              <li>Child 2</li>
              <li id="child_8">Child 1</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```